# Trying to remove the use of malloc - is there an alternative here?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, fread

Apologies for the vague title.

I am currently refactoring some code written by a previous developer on the team. We are currently using malloc to assign X space in memory to be written to.

```
char* foo = NULL;
foo = (char*)malloc((uint32_t)fSize + 1);
bar = (int64_t)fread(foo, (uint32_t)fSize, 1, fd);
foo[fSize] = '\0';
```

Where fSize is the size of an .sql file we're reading

man fread tells me that it will read 1 item(s) of size fSize from fd (stream) and write to the memory location pointed to by foo.

Essentially I am trying to find a way to keep the same functionality we have now without using malloc. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with memory allocation etc and this is one of my first times coming across it so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: sure this is the current code? if I understood the question should be foo = (char*)malloc((uint32_t)fSize + 1);

Comment: wat, ``malloc((uint32_t)+1)` allocates **one** byte of space, which is slightly less than 4-8 bytes for pointer

Comment: Change to an array?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I edited the OP. malloc((uint32_t)fSize+1)

Comment: All that matters is how large the file is. If it is large, you _should_ use dynamic allocation.

Comment: Our largest file is 8KB

Comment: @Shox2711 if you are sure your  largest files are 8KB, just use a static 8kb buffer. Or even use a local variable like: `char foo[8192 + 1]`, provided the stack is large enough on your platform.

Comment: The whole of stdio.h is banned from production code by MISRA-C, so I'm not sure if this discussion is even relevant, since MISRA-C is de facto industry standard for everything automotive.

Comment: That's interesting - I didn't know that. To be honest I'm just a new grad on the team. This my first time working in automotive and embedded systems in general. Most of these discussions go over my head but posting this question was a good learning experience at the very least. Ultimately I'm just following the tickets I'm being assigned and doing the work associated.. in this case to remove the use of this malloc. (appreciate all the input and discussion by the way, it's been helpful!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dealing with a simple types (`char`), you may easily allocate the memory on the stack and read there:

```
char foo[fSize+1];   // '+1' is not required, but why not? =)
bar = (int64_t)fread( foo, (uint32_t)fSize, 1, fd);
```

For the more complicated structures you may want to declare those first and then use for the memory allocation, the good point of allocation on the stack is that the deallocation is automatically taken care of when the function ends, you don't have to call `free()` explicitly.

Comment: My apologies, I wrote it incorrectly. I have fixed it above in the op. Should be (uint32_t)fSize + 1

Comment: @CianO'Shaughnessy I know, my answer still stands =)

Comment: This depends solely on how large the file is. Allocating several MB on the stack through VLA is a bad idea.

Comment: Just reading over your answer trying to understand it correctly, looks good :). Just to add one point regarding the [fSize=1], I was told the reason we were adding +1 was for the terminating character. The next line below what I have posted is foo[fSize] = '\0'; Is this needed do you think?

Comment: *If you're dealing with a simple types* -- you mean, if you are dealing with very small files? `char foo[10000000]` is far worse than `struct whatever foo[3];`.

Comment: Regarding wanting to remove malloc - we need to follow certain ISO standards (automotive) and malloc is a no-no apparently.

Comment: @CianO'Shaughnessy Depends on whether the null terminator is stored in the file or not.

Comment: @CianO'Shaughnessy: stack overflow is likely also a no-no in automotive though. What you probably want to do is have a large static array (which you can potentially reuse as needed for different tasks, making sure you are not writing to it concurrently from different threads/interrupts).

Comment: Note: this only "works" if the C compiler supports VLAs, which is *not* required per C11 and later. For those C implementations that define `__STDC_NO_VLA__` to integer 1 (and therefore proclaim no VLA support), a dynamic solution is really the only option.

Comment: Won't go into too much details on a public site but what we're doing comes directly from ISO 14229

Comment: @CianO'Shaughnessy So if I get this right... you have a requirement "do not use explosives". The previous dev used fireworks before launching the atomic bomb. And now you are looking for other explosive alternatives to use instead of fireworks, before launching the atomic bomb. While what you actually should be doing according to your spec is to remove everything that could explode.

Comment: @CianO'Shaughnessy - your company needs a senior embedded programmer who will set up all the general stuff.  Someone who has a lots of experience with MISRA and related topics.

Comment: @Groo he needs memory pools allocation service.

Comment: @Lundin *This exactly is the kind of stuff that makes me afraid of cars.* What really scares me is `(uint32_t)fSize`.  Why did someone think that cast was necessary?  What happens when `fSize` is -2?  That's one skunky code smell.

Comment: @Shox2711 i used to work in automotive. if you need any help, please, don't hesitate to contact.

Comment: @lenik thank you very much for offering, I may take you up on that in the future :) And I just tested the new impl with your suggestions and it's all working smoothly. Much appreciated once again!